# What math topic(s) should i study to understand and represent non-linear movements?

Tags: graph-theory, physics, bezier-curve

I want to understand it so i can make formulas/equations to apply on Web animations and etc. [Example](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67)

In the example, the movement is represented by some kind of Cartesian System, i guess.

What math is behind animations like that? I've seen something there about Bezier Curves, but i didn't understand it at all. What math topics should i study so i can finally understand it?

Thanks in advance!

*PS: Sorry if i haven't categorized this question correctly. As i said before, i don't know exactly the correct math topic for it...* =)

Comment: Sorry for any grammar errors too. English isn't my native language. I'm doing my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some simple algebra, functions of one variable; enough to understand what a graph is and what it means. Then you need a little differential calculus, because this covers derivatives, which are the key to motion and speeds. To understand Bezier curves, it would help to know about 2D/3D vectors and parametric equations.

That should give you enough terms to look up  :-)